# Stringgrid wordwrap displays text twice

Tags: delphi, vcl, tstringgrid

I want to display a long string in a string grid cell in a wordwrap format and found the following code to do so:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
//enable wordwrap in cells
var
  S: String;
  drawrect :trect;
begin
  stringgrid1.Canvas.FillRect (Rect);
  S:= (Sender As TStringgrid).Cells [ACol, ARow ];
  If Length(S) > 0 Then Begin
    drawrect := rect;
    DrawText((Sender As TStringgrid).canvas.handle,
              Pchar(S), Length(S), drawrect,
              dt_calcrect or dt_wordbreak or dt_left );
    If (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.top) >
       (Sender As TStringgrid).RowHeights[Arow]
    Then
      (Sender As TStringgrid).RowHeights[Arow] :=
         (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.top)
      // changing the row height fires the event again!
    Else Begin
      drawrect.Right := rect.right;

      (Sender As TStringgrid).canvas.fillrect( drawrect );
      DrawText((Sender As TStringgrid).canvas.handle,
                Pchar(S), Length(S), drawrect,
                dt_wordbreak or dt_left);
    End;
  End;
end;
```

The word wrap works but the cell displays both the original text and the wrapped text.  I assume that that since this is an onDrawCell event that the original text is already drawn and I would erase it with the first line of code (stringgrid1.canvas.fillrect(rect), but this has no effect on the display. What am I missing?

Comment: Do not setup row height from a drawing event. That in turn triggers drawing event again.

Comment: It sounds like you still have `DefaultDrawing` enabled. The appropriate thing would be to disable it, but you also are then responsible for *all* drawing.

Comment: @Victoria  Since stringgrid does not perform a wordwrap, I have to use the onDrawCell event to modify the cell size and display the text.

Comment: No, you don't have to. You're not supposed to do that, actually. It's actually you who set the cell text, so do the measurement and set the row height there (`TStringGrid` is old, not flexible control). And, also when the column is resized if you allow it (but that requires the grid class interception).

Comment: @JerryDodge  I want to avoid drawing the entire stringgrid myself.  Since this code executes after the initial drawing, I expected the fillrect. to overwrite the text original display and then repainting the text wrapped.

Comment: @victoria.  I followed your suggestion, but changing the row height when I assign the text string to the cell does not result in a wordwrap of the string even though the cell is now high enough to accommodate the text on multiple lines.

Answer (score 5):

> ...would erase it with the first line of code
>   (stringgrid1.canvas.fillrect(rect), but this has no effect on the
>   display

That is because you did not select the `Brush.Style` (and possibly also `Brush.Color`) just before calling `FillRect()` f.ex.

```
  stringgrid1.canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid; // add this line
  stringgrid1.canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite; // add this line
  stringgrid1.Canvas.FillRect (Rect);
```

You will notice that there are some remnants from the default drawing at the left edge of the cells (not visible in the image below, I already fixed them). That is because the `TStringGrid` internally offsets the cell drawing with 4 pixels. To change that you need to counter offset the `Rect` parameter with -4 and grow the width with +4, also before calling `FillRect()`.

After above changes the grid looks very flat and dull (in the image I already added colors to the second grid). To reinstate some color differances for the header column and header row, you need to treat cells with `gdFixed in State` with a different `Brush.Color`. The same for cells with `gdSelected in State`.

[image]

The above is what you also need to do if you untick `DefaultDrawing`. The second grid and accompanying code demonstrates this. Note that the code also includes a call to `DrawFocusRect` when `gdFocused in State` just before the end.

Note that I replaced all those `Sender as TStringGrid` with a local `grid` variable.

```
procedure TForm4.StringGrid2DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect;
  State: TGridDrawState);
var
  grid: TStringGrid;
  S: String;
  drawrect: TRect;
  bgFill: TColor;
begin
  grid := Sender as TStringGrid;

  if gdFixed in State then
    bgFill := $FFF8F8
  else
  if gdSelected in State then
    bgFill := $FFF0D0
  else
    bgFill := clWhite;

  grid.Canvas.Brush.Color := bgFill;
  grid.canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  grid.canvas.fillrect(Rect);

  S := grid.Cells[ACol, ARow];
  if Length(S) > 0 then
  begin
    drawrect := Rect;
    drawrect.Inflate(-4 , 0);
    DrawText(grid.canvas.handle, Pchar(S), Length(S), drawrect,
      dt_calcrect or dt_wordbreak or dt_left);
    If (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.top) > grid.RowHeights[ARow] then
      grid.RowHeights[ARow] := (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.top+2)
      // changing the row height fires the event again!
    else
    begin
      drawrect.Right := Rect.Right;

//      grid.canvas.fillrect(drawrect);
      DrawText(grid.canvas.handle, Pchar(S), Length(S), drawrect,
        dt_wordbreak or dt_left);
    end;
  end;

  if gdFocused in State then
    grid.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
end;
```

**The third grid demonstrates** the easiest and IMO the best solution, wich is to skip the `TStringGrid` altogether and use `TDrawGrid` instead. You must keep the data you want to show in the grid, separately somewhere. I defined an array: `s_arr: array of array of string;`.

In this case you can leave `DefaultDrawing` on because the `TDrawGrid` doesn't draw any text during the default drawing, the content drawing takes place only in the `OnDrawCell` event.

```
procedure TForm4.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect;
  State: TGridDrawState);
var
  S: string;
  grid: TDrawGrid;
  drawrect: TRect;
begin
  grid := Sender as TDrawGrid;
  S := s_arr[ACol, ARow];
  If Length(S) > 0 Then
  Begin
    drawrect := Rect;
    drawrect.Inflate(-4 , 0);
    DrawText(grid.canvas.handle, Pchar(S), Length(S), drawrect,
      dt_calcrect or dt_wordbreak or dt_left);
    If (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.top) > grid.RowHeights[ARow] Then
      grid.RowHeights[ARow] := (drawrect.bottom - drawrect.top + 2)
      // changing the row height fires the event again!
    Else
    Begin
      drawrect.Right := Rect.Right;

      grid.canvas.fillrect(drawrect);
      DrawText(grid.canvas.handle, Pchar(S), Length(S), drawrect, dt_wordbreak or dt_left);
    End;
  End;
end;
```

Leaving `DefaultDrawing` on, all those theme related features are drawn by the grid itself and we only draw the text on top.